# AngularJs + JQueryUI waiting for response

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

I am trying to make some useful directives with jQueryUI widgets for my AngularJS base application.

One of them works on "**select**" element and am ok with directives but only thing  do not understand is this one:

1. When select list is populated from ajax request, how to tell to apply jqueryui widget when data is populated? Suppose it is with $watch but not sure how.

**Edit:**
In example I am trying to implement directive for the [multiselect plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).
Please note that I am simulating server reponse but putting everything in timeout.

Here is a [code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SoVw7k)

Comment: Do you have the code you are using? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be $watching changes to the items list, then calling `refresh` on the multiselect plugin...  [Here is a plunk that shows the solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJRH2I)

```
angular.module('myui', [])
    .directive('qnMultiselect', function() {
        return { 
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            //set up the plugin.
            elem.multiselect({ allowClear: false });

            //get the source of the ngOptions
            var parts = attr.ngOptions.split(' ');
            var source = parts[parts.length - 1];

            //watch the options source and refresh the plugin.
            scope.$watch(source, function(value) {
              elem.multiselect('refresh');
            });
          }        
        };
    });
```